# Rebuilding data from two tables and renaming rows from table data

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, transpose

I'm trying to reconstruct data from two tables within a database.  The first table (data) contains the time value and code.  The second table (signals) contains the code and description.  Ideally, I'd like to end up with the results table shown below with the columns grouped by timestamp and the row names changed to the descriptor text.

I've managed to do this post SQL query using groupings and multiple transposes but this does not scale very well.

Is it possible to carry out all these functions within an SQL query?

Data Table

```
TIMESTAMP           CODE        VALUE 
2016-05-11 13:56:47 1000.ME     26.900 
2016-05-11 13:56:47 1313.ME     9.1136 
2016-05-11 13:56:51 1313.ME     9.1233 
2016-05-11 13:56:56 1313.ME     9.1136 
2016-05-11 13:57:00 1000.ME     27 
2016-05-11 13:57:00 1313.ME     9.1331
```

Signals Table

```
CODE       DESCRIPTOR
1000.ME    Inlet Thermpcouple
1313.ME    Air Flow
```

Results Table

```
Timestamp              Inlet Thermpcouple    Air Flow 
2016-05-11 13:56:47    26.900                9.1136 
2016-05-11 13:56:51    26.900                9.1233
2016-05-11 13:56:56    26.900                9.1136 
2016-05-11 13:57:00    27                    9.1331
```

Comment: In your desired output, why do 2nd and 3rd row have 26.900? For that timestamp you have no value for Inlet Thermpcouple, so how can you chose 26.900 and not 27 or null?

Comment: You can't do that dynamically, using the rows in the signal table to determine the columns in the result set, in plain SQL. (Unless you want the output in XML, anyway). With fixed values you can get that data easily, but not with dynamic values.

Comment: @AlexPoole - Ha, I'm glad I mentioned that, otherwise I would have had to edit my post.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Good practice, thank you for posting your question!

Here is one way to do what you need. There are three parts to the problem: First, you need to join the two tables so that you have the actual descriptors instead of codes. Second, you need to pivot so that Inlet Thermocouple and Air Flow readings are separated into two columns. Third, if for one timestamp you only have a value for Air Flow but no value for Inlet Thermocouple, you want the IT value to be filled with the most recent reading (value).

The join is trivial, and the third part is a direct application of the `LAG()` function with the `IGNORE NULLS` option. (Note - this function allows a windowing clause; the default is `rows between unbounded preceding and current row` which is exactly what we need, so I didn't use this parameter - the default is perfect.)

The only glitch is that - unless you use dynamic SQL - you **must** know the number and names of columns in every table you work with in a SQL statement. So it doesn't help to have "Inlet Thermocouple" and "Air Flow" as descriptors in your table - they are still **hard-coded** in the statement. So, you either are OK with that and you can write your queries this way, or you will need to develop dynamic SQL code.

Below are the code, including your test data, and then the output from the query.

```
with data_table (ts, code, val) as (
        select to_timestamp('2016-05-11 13:56:47', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 
                                                   '1000.ME', 26.9      from dual union all
        select to_timestamp('2016-05-11 13:56:47', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 
                                                   '1313.ME',  9.1136   from dual union all
        select to_timestamp('2016-05-11 13:56:51', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 
                                                   '1313.ME',  9.1233   from dual union all
        select to_timestamp('2016-05-11 13:56:56', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 
                                                   '1313.ME',  9.1136   from dual union all
        select to_timestamp('2016-05-11 13:57:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 
                                                   '1000.ME', 27        from dual union all
        select to_timestamp('2016-05-11 13:57:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'), 
                                                   '1313.ME',  9.1331   from dual
     ),
     signals_table (code, descriptor) as (
        select '1000.ME', 'Inflow Thermocouple' from dual union all
        select '1313.ME', 'Air Flow'            from dual
     ),
     j as (
        select d.ts, s.descriptor, d.val from data_table d 
                                   inner join signals_table s on d.code = s.code
     ),
     p as (
        select * from j 
           pivot (min(val) for descriptor in ('Inflow Thermocouple' as it, 
                                              'Air Flow' as af))
     )
select ts, last_value(it ignore nulls) over (order by ts) as "Inflow Thermocouple",
           last_value(af ignore nulls) over (order by ts) as "Air Flow"
from p
order by ts;
```

Note - the output below shows actual timestamp datatype; I wasn't sure if your "timestamp" column is in fact DATE datatype or true timestamp, the query should work either way. Also, it is generally a very bad idea to use Oracle keywords (such as "timestamp" or "date") as table or column names in the database. I changed that to ts.

```
TS                                            Inflow Thermocouple   Air Flow
--------------------------------------------- ------------------- ----------
11-MAY-16 01.56.47.000000000                                 26.9     9.1136
11-MAY-16 01.56.51.000000000                                 26.9     9.1233
11-MAY-16 01.56.56.000000000                                 26.9     9.1136
11-MAY-16 01.57.00.000000000                                   27     9.1331
```

Comment: Yeah, I have a similar solution I decided not to post; but the signals table is irrelevant, since you're hard-coding the values anyway you can do it with a pivot straight from the data table. Well, I guess I'm assuming fixed codes, you're just assuming fixed descriptors, which is a bit more flexible. Adding a new row to the signals table would need the query to be amended to match still.

Comment: Right - I assume there may be more than one code assigned to Air Flow readings, for example. The query would only need to be modified if there are more descriptors; if there are more rows assigning different (new) codes to either Inflow Thermocouple or to Air Flow, the query would need no change.

Comment: Fair enough, and using the descriptors makes the important parts of the query clearer. I still think the OP wants a dynamic answer, but this might be as close as they can get in plain SQL.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the quick reply!

Realistically though the data could run for hours and there are 30+  descriptors.

Sounds like I need some dynamic SQL code or I stick with my slow solution.

Thanks again.